# How to import python script from another directory at parent level?

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import `script1.py` from `script2.py` but getting this error:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

```
Parent_Dir/
    __init__.py
    Child1/
        script1.py
    Child2/
        __init__.py 
        script2.py
```

I've tried a lot of ways to do this but none of them worked for me.
This is what I've tried:

`from .Child1 import script1`

`from ..Child1 import script1`

`from .Parent_Dir.Child1 import script1`

`from Parent_Dir.Child1 import script1`

I know there are a lot of similar questions on SOF but most of them are either using `sys` or `os` or `importlib` or `PYTHONPATH`. Is there any way to do this **without using any module and without using `path` or `PYTHONPATH`** ( I mean by using import statements only).

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) see this link.

Comment: Why are `script1` and `script2` inside a package? If they are literally scripts (as opposed to modules), they should be in the top-level directory (i.e. the one that contains `Parent_Dir`). Any functionality required by both scripts should go in the modules inside the package. Then the imports will all work as expected.

Comment: @liamsuma I've tried these answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170807/12566054,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995949/12566054) but they didn't work for me.